# Return a string to Windows from context menu (C#)

Tags: c#

A common thing I do is name files by the current date/time. For instance, I'll name something `12-31-2016-08-46-01.jpg`

This is great. It works well. But typing it every time is annoying, so I thought it useful to just write a small program that returns the output as a string. That was easy enough.

```
public class Program {
   public static string Main() {
      var strFilename = new DateTimeFilename();
      return strFilename.Current();
   }
public class DateTimeFilename {

   public string Current () {
      return // ... logic ... //
   }
}
```

And then I add this program as a context menu option in the Windows registry.

Except that doesn't work. Apparently, I cannot return a `string` from the actual program.

So is there a way to get the `string` out of the program and into whatever my cursor is trying to type into at the time?

Comment: Copy it to the clipboard instead.

Comment: How can you invoke a context menu on a file while changing a file's name?

Comment: Maybe I can't. I was actually trying to do this with the `Save As ...` dialog first, and just kind of expected it would work the same way for editing a file name.

Comment: Copying it to the clipboard might work. I'll give that a try, thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you could create a program which uses SendKeys() to output the current date and time in a particular format when you invoke it

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you work within Windows File Explorer and add a `Send To` option which does this operation and passes the current selected file name to the clipboard.

The following takes the selected filename and adds a custom date after the name, but before the extension, such as `TheFile.20211123.txt`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0])}.{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}{Path.GetExtension(args[0])}";
    // MessageBox.Show(name);
    Clipboard.SetText(name);
}
```

- Build the program and the create a file explorer short cut to the exe built. Then place the shortcut to this folder:

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`

- Then in File Explorer right click, select `Send To` and select the shortcut name you gave it.
- Then paste the new name where ever you need it, for it resides in your clipboard.